# How to read a value from env file to decide whether to execute GitLab CI stage?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a variable stored into env file :

```
stages:
  - build
  - execute   

build:
    stage: build
    script:
     - Add-Content properties.env -Value PROD="TRUE"
artifacts:
  reports:
    dotenv: properties.env
tags:
    - windows
```

**Now i wanted to read this value in a stage and then decide whether to execute that stage or not.**

I did the following, but it isn't working:

```
execute:
    stage: execute
    rules:
    - if: $PROD == "TRUE"
      when: always
    script:
     - echo "happy"
    tags:
      - windows
    dependencies: 
      - build
```

Any help ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use the approach described in "[Pass an environment variable to another job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job)":

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "BUILD_VERSION=hello" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

deploy_one:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "$BUILD_VERSION"  # Output is: 'hello'
  dependencies:
    - build
  environment:
    name: customer1
    deployment_tier: production
```